# Filtering Google Search Results to the relevant content in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I do web scraping of Google Search Results in Python to get news links and when I click on the news link it does not include the relevant searched keyword, but actual related news is in the corner of the page. Is there any way to get specifically the link of that relevant news in the corner?

Also some Google Search results are completely irrelevant to the searched word.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: Scarping Google search results supposedly is a violation of their terms of usage. So we probably shouldn't be helping you with this "illegal" activity.

Comment: Gunel ! use `serpapi` or `zenserp` or  `GOOGLE API`